# make etc/hosts file readable on docker from docker file

Tags: bash, docker, networking, dockerfile, hosts

I want to modify permissions etc/hosts file in docker as I am continuously modifying it. I want to make particular user have the access or have the 744 access on it. I tried following in docker file.

```
USE root
RUN chown <user>:<group> /etc/hosts
```

```
USE root
RUN chmod 777 /etc/hosts
```

However this doesn't work and throws an exception on saying that etc/host is readable and hence can't change permission.

Comment: I'd avoid changing `/etc/hosts` if at all possible.  I'd _definitely_ avoid making a system-level file like this world-writeable; `chmod 0777` is almost always a security mistake.  Since Docker manages the network environment of the container in general, you can't edit `/etc/hosts` in a Dockerfile.  If you really absolutely can't set up a DNS server, the linked question describes a `docker run --add-host` option that's an alternative.

Comment: i need it for experiment purpose. The idea is I am testing something but for that I need to keep editing etc/hosts file only issue is that the docker file is not able to modify it even if i try to run above commands as it says that the file is readonly. I am able to do docker exec and change the command though but i need a docker file solution.

Comment: Any way just to test the approach? Everytime i try to change permission it says `changing permissions of '/etc/hosts': Read-only file system` even though i am root. but if i make the container up and run docker compose exec then the command runs.